# Fix wordpress query (add if have)

Tags: wordpress

```
<ul>
<?php
global $post;
$args = array( 'numberposts' => 12, 'orderby' => 'date', 'year' => '2012', 'order' => 'ASC', 'document_language' => 'english');
$myposts = get_documents( $args );
foreach( $myposts as $post ) :  setup_postdata($post); ?>
    <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
<?php endforeach; 
?>
</ul>
```

How can I put the  into if have posts query? It's basically custom post type query but its using document revisions plugin (so get_posts is get_documents)?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to check if the query returned any posts. You can still do it with your code.

Here is example:

```
<?php

    global $post;

    // This is your query
    $args = array( 'numberposts' => 12, 'orderby' => 'date', 'year' => '2012', 'order' => 'ASC', 'document_language' => 'english');
    $myposts = get_documents( $args );

    if (count($myposts) > 0 ) : // If the query returned results

    ?>

    <ul>

        <?php foreach( $myposts as $post ) :  setup_postdata($post); // for each post in array ?>
            <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>

    </ul>

    <?php endif; ?>
```